# freeSSHD cannot be accessed by scp

Tags: scp

I am running freeSSHD on Windows A, and need to transfer file with it by scp. The Windows running freesshd can be connected via ssh client. but neither WinSCP on Windows nor scp on Linux cannot connect to the Windows with freeSSHD. The errors are:

on Linux:

```
test@workstation:~$ scp -r /home/test/scptest test@192.168.91.238:/C:\Users\dejavu\Desktop
test@192.168.91.238's password: 
exec request failed on channel 0
lost connection
```

on windows:

'scp' protocol is selected to transfer file and the port is default 22. 
The error is simply `host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds. still waiting...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scp`, as many other things, is two-side protocol. It requires `scp` to be present on both client and server. When you issue copy command, `ssh` connects to given server and spawns `scp` process, which your local `scp` then communicates with. In your case, there is no `scp` on server, so no communication possible.

`rsync` behaves in exactly the same way.

I guess in your case you could try `sftp`.

Comment: Thanks for your clue! I can access windows with freesshd from winscp throught "sftp" now. But my final purpose is to use fabric.operations.put/get to transfer with windows with freesshd. Guess i have to change the ssh server or use alternative way to transfer files now.

Comment: I think you could just copy `scp.exe` into one of system directories (one of PATH, e.g. `C:\windows\system32`). It is not part of ssh. Winscp have one, if I remember correctly.

Comment: My fault. i thought fabric used scp in put/get. instead it is using sftp. and enabling sftp in freesshd works now! Thanks!